# Access phpfpm inside docker container with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, fastcgi

Can the phpfpm inside the docker container be accessed from outside with nginx fastcgi_pass?

i have installed nginx on my ubuntu with apt install nginx and i'm want to configure nginx with phpfpm but phpfpm in docker container

docker-compose

```
version: "2"
services:
  phpfpm:
   image: bitnami/php-fpm:7.1
   container_name: "phpfpm_7.1"
   ports:
    - 9000:9000

   network_mode: "host"

   volumes:
    - ./tester/:/app
```

nginx config

```
location ~* \.php$ {
                 fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_nam$
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

try access file php in browser ,nginx say File not found.

Comment: What about directly visit 127.0.0.1:9000 from browser or curl?

Comment: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly its works im trying to change docker compose file to

```
version: "2"
services:

 phpfpm7:
   image: bitnami/php-fpm:7.1
   container_name: "phpfpm_7.1"
   volumes:
     - /var/www/:/var/www/
   networks:
      vpcbr:
           ipv4_address: 192.168.85.2


networks:
   vpcbr:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        config:
         - subnet: 192.168.85.0/24
```

nginx config :

```
fastcgi_pass 192.168.85.2:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
```